message: `RDSHttp:{"message":"The schema parameter isn't supported."}` I am getting this error when calling api fro appsync and rds
I am getting this error and my 2-3 app is affected.Can Anyone help me to resolve it
I tried most of the way provided ,If I am creating new Api then its working but for older one its not working.If Anyone have got this error can Please help me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you can try to remove the schema key from your C:\Workspace\Project-Github\project-name\amplify\backend\api\appname\stacks\appname_dev-rds.json file. like: "Schema": "mysql",
and if you are facing the same issue on the lambda function while hitting rds then remove the schema key from your db file as well. like: schema: 'PUBLIC',

Second Solution You are telling where we can get and if you are facing the same issue on the lambda function while hitting rds then remove the schema key from your db file as well. like: schema: 'PUBLIC', this??

and first solution you are saying that file name dose not exist only at that speciifed path
